# Having issues with Pandas "Sum within Groups"

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone help me understand why I am having issues with using "groupby and sum" in Pandas. I have data where `col_1` is a string and `col_2` is a column of ones I am using to create additional variables by group. I have the following for calculating a cumulative sum within groups that appears to work as expected:

```
df['var'] = df.groupby(['col_1'])['col_2'].cumsum()
```

(this is working fine to my knowledge)

However, when I attempt to calculate a sum or max by group, the resulting column is all `nan` and I am struggling to understand how or why this is happening to me.

```
df['var'] = df.groupby(['col_1'])['col_2'].cumsum()
```

(this is creating a column of `nan`)

Appreciate the help here - thanks!

I was trying to calcuate a sum by group (which should be 1 or 2) but instead am receiving just `nan` values.

Comment: You have NaNs because of incorrect index alignment. You need to use `transform('sum')`